# Apple Mail: Adding two or more standard actions

Tags: mail.app, archive, mail-rules

I am happily using Apple Mail and have ordered my mail chaos into a great structured  tree of certain archive directories.  I use apple Mail rules to organize a lot of the incoming traffic to be sorted into the according archive directories automatically.

Unfortunately, there are some incoming mails, which can't be sorted by a rule (unless you blow up the rule to have endless decisions and dare to completely mess it up).

Luckily, the remaining mails will be stored in two or three different archive directories.  Therefore it would make a lot of sense to me, to add some custom actions to the context menu or the menu symbol area (is that the correct translation from the german expression?)

I tried to customize the symbol area, you can of course add a "move"-button, it is in fact a drop down menu, which offers all archive directories, I have defined.  This is tedious, I just want to have three buttons, each dedicated to a specific archiv directory.